# How to set the 'spring' force with graphviz for compact graph layouts

Tags: graphviz, neato

I'm generating diagram with [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and I have a problem - there are several nodes that are very large - and large number of small nodes. I tried generating png with [*neato*](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/neatoguide.pdf) and [*fdp*](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/undirected/fdpclust.html) but both generate very large graphics, which are mostly blank (nodes are very far apart). Is there a way to set a larger spring 'strength' for these tools to force nodes closer together?

Comment: Knowing this post is very old: if using sfdp/fdp, there's an attribute called [K](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:K), which serves for this purpose.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using neato, you may fiddle with the `overlap` and with the `sep` attribute.

`overlap` can be set to `false`, `compress`, `scalexy`, and [more](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:overlap).

[`sep`](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:sep) may either designate an additive margin when used with a preceding plus sign, otherwise the margin is defined by scaling the node's size with 1 + the value of `sep`. It seems that the default

Don't hesitate to post a sample graph. Not knowing your particular graph, I made an example containing some big and some small nodes:

```
layout=neato;
overlap=scalexy; //false, compress, ...
sep="+1"; // 0.1, +1

node[label="Large node", width=2, height=2];
l1; l2; l3;
node[label="\N", width=0.5, height=0.3];
1 -> l1;
2 -> l1;
3 -> l1;
4 -> l1;
5 -> l1;
5 -> l2;
6 -> l2;
7 -> l2;
8 -> l2;
8 -> l3;
9 -> l3;
10 -> l3;
```

[image]

Comment: sep="+1"  fixed for  "Found unexpected character '+' "

Comment: @qxo looks like now you have to put it between quotes `sep="+1";`